# Independence in Binomial Distribution

Tags: independence

Let $X \thicksim B(n,p)$ then show that

$E[X(X-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(X-r+1)] = n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-r+1)p^r ,\;r = 1,2,...n$

---

To prove above statement, I had chosen to prove below claim first

**claim** : $X, X-k$ are independent when $k = 0, 1,...r-1 $

First I had used the property $E(X\cdot X-k) = E(X)\cdot E(X-k)$ but had realized that it is necessary condition of independence not sufficient.

Then only I have to do is to derive joint pdf of $X, X-k$ then compare it to multiplication of marginal ones.

How could one derive joint pdf of $X, X-k$?

Comment: Why do you think $X$ and $X-k$ might be independent? What about the case $k=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ E[X(X-1)\ldots (X-r+1)] = \sum_{x=r}^n x(x-1)\ldots (x-r+1) P(X=x) $$

Then see that $x(x-1)\ldots (x-r+1) = \frac{x!}{(x-r)!}$

So 
$$ E[X(X-1)\ldots (X-r+1)] = \sum_{x=r}^n \frac{x!}{(x-r)!} \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x(1-p)^{n-x} = \sum_{x=0}^n  \frac{n!}{(x-r)!(n-x)!}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$

So we have $$ \sum_{x=r}^n   {{n-r}\choose {x-r}} n(n-1)\ldots (n-r+1) p^rp^{x-r}(1-p)^{n-x}$$

Now let's take everything that does not depend on $x$ outside of bracket:

$$ n(n-1)\ldots (n-r+1) p^r \left( \sum_{x=r}^n   {{n-r}\choose {x-r}} p^{x-r}(1-p)^{n-x} \right) $$

Now introducing $y=x-r$ into big bracket we get 
$$\left( \sum_{y=0}^{n-r}   {{n-r}\choose {y}} p^{y}(1-p)^{n-r-y} \right) $$

And this equals to 1 since it is a $\sum_{y=0}^{n-r} P(Y=y)$ with $Y \sim B(n-r, p)$.